# Primeng control <p-multiSelect> accessibility not working

Tags: angular, accessibility, primeng

I'm using Primeng multiselect control given below.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect

I want to make multiselect control accessible compliant, I'm using primeng version 11.4.2

As shown below, multiselect control seems to be accessible compliant (even though I found few issues) when I test in https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect website using below keys.

1. Space bar Key -> Open multiselect control options.
2. Tab Key ->  Navigate among options.
3. Enter Key -> Select option.

[image]

Above are working in official primeng portal, but when I integrate same control in my angular application, it seems to be not working. Only Space bar Key working to open multiselect options but when I use Tab key to navigate between multiselect options, I'm unable to do that. When I press Tab key, instead of navigating between options, focus moved to another control.

I'm not getting what else need to be added to make primeng controls to be compliant for accessibility.

Pls suggest.

Comment: Tab key shouldn't be used to navigate between options anyway, the general rule is tab to move between controls and arrow keys within controls. Have you seen if arrow keys work to move up and down?